# HttpWebRequest POST data

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to make an exact identical POST with HttpWebRequest in C# as a browser would? Without a page being able to detect that it is actually no browser?

If so, were could i read up more on that?

Comment: UserAgent - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057328/httpwebrequest-useragent-what-does-it-do

Comment: @seth flowers is correct use Fiddler. You can capture posts and replay them. If nothing else it will give you the information need to duplicate the post.

Comment: No site would be able to detect that? Its always possible with Fiddler and HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Just trying to understand difference between a browser and HttpWebRequest :)

Comment: Fiddler will allow you to actually see the actual web-request. You can set some property in HttpWebRequest and see it in action inside fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and become familiar with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It allows you to inspect web requests made from applications, like a normal browser, and see exactly what is being sent. You can then emulate the data being sent with a request created in C#, providing values for headers, cookies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is doable.

Browser detection is done based on a header in the request. All you need to do is set that header. In HttpWebRequest we dont need to set the headers collection but rather the .UserAgent property.

Eg:

```
.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)";
```

There is quite a lot to user agents. Check [this](http://www.user-agents.org/) link for the complete list of User-Agents

Useful Links:

[How to create a simple proxy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226784/how-to-create-a-simple-proxy-in-c) 
[Is WebRequest The Right C# Tool For Interacting With Websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91275/is-webrequest-the-right-c-sharp-tool-for-interacting-with-websites) 
http://codehelp.smartdev.eu/2009/05/08/improve-webclient-by-adding-useragent-and-cookies-to-your-requests/