# Writing an RSS Reader for a password-protected feed, connection timing out

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

At this point, I'm just trying to get a response from the website. Here's my code:

```
private void GetFeed(string userName, string password, string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.Timeout = 1000;

    NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
    request.Credentials = netCred;

    try
    {
        WebResponse wr = request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

My username and password are *definitely* correct, I've quadruple checked it, so it has to be something to do with how I'm connecting. I think my code is pretty straightforward, but let me know if I need to explain anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and become familiar with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see how to post exactly what your browser posts to the website. It could be that the site is expecting certain cookies or other headers.

See [HttpWebRequest POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541270/httpwebrequest-post-data/10541342#10541342)