# Is there anything in the C# library that would simulate the Navigator object in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, http

I need to simulate some JavaScript code using C#. In particular, I need to write some code in C# that'd parallel some functionalities of the Navigator object in JavaScript.

This site introduces the Navigator object in the JavaScript library.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp

Is there a method/function in the C# library that'd simulate the JavaScipt method navigator.userAgent? (for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp)

How about navigator.language? ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp )

In fact, which methods in the Navigator object can be simulated by C#? And which ones cannot?

Thank you!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057328/httpwebrequest-useragent-what-does-it-do

Comment: Can you explain in what sense you need to "simulate" navigator objects? Are you trying to create web requests that match once send by browsers?

Comment: Alexei Levenkov: I mean the corresponding code in C# should produce the same result/output as the code in JavaScript (which uses the Navigator object). So I need methods/functions in the C# library that would parallel the functionality of the Navigator object in JavaScript. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are after [Browser Types and Capabilites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3yekbd5b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). These are avaiable in the Request object:

```
Request.Browser
```