# WebRequest receive The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

When I visit this URL in the Chrome Browser, it works and I can see a string there:
https://cex.io/api/ticker/BTC/USD

However, when I try to request the above URL using the below code. I do receive this error message:
**The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden**

I wonder what could be wrong with the code or if I need to add or change something to return the string as we do in the chrome browser?

```
public void request()
{
    String responseBody = "";
    String requestString = "https://cex.io/api/ticker/BTC/USD";

    try
    {
        //Make the request
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestString);

        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)";
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Method = "GET"; //GET, POST
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                try
                {
                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch { }
            }
            response.Close();
            response.Dispose();
            responseBody = responseBody.ToLower();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        //Show Error
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    MessageBox.Show(responseBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the website in question does not support the IE6 browser family, but you are specifying that as your user agent.  You can either drop it or change it to a different browser and the code will work.  My recommendation would be to drop it altogether since you are just making a data request to get the JSON and so it doesn't really matter what "browser" you are.  You can read more about `UserAgent` and what it is used for at this SO post [HttpWebRequest.UserAgent : What does it do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057328/httpwebrequest-useragent-what-does-it-do)

This website has a list of standard user agents: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

This will set your UserAgent as Mozilla 2.2.

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201";
```